# Scope in generic functions R

Tags: r, scope

If you define a variable inside a generic function, it is available to the method. For example:

```
g <- function(x) {
  y <- 2
  UseMethod("g")
}
g.default <- function() y
g()
[1] 2
```

But if the variable you define has the same name as the function parameter, this does not happen. It seems that R deletes that variable before calling the method:

```
g <- function(x) {
  x <- 2
  UseMethod("g")
}
g.default <- function() x
g()
Error in g.default() : object 'x' not found
```

Could someone explain exactly what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following comments from the [C source file that defines `do_usemethod`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/objects.c#L168) at least hint at what's going on. See especially the second sentence of the second enumerated item.

Basically, it looks like (due to dumb application of rule in that second point), the value of x does not get copied over because the C code checks to see if it's among the formals, sees that it is, and so excludes if from the list of variables inserted into the method's evaluation environment.

```
/* usemethod - calling functions need to evaluate the object
* (== 2nd argument). They also need to ensure that the
* argument list is set up in the correct manner.
*
* 1. find the context for the calling function (i.e. the generic)
* this gives us the unevaluated arguments for the original call
*
* 2. create an environment for evaluating the method and insert
* a handful of variables (.Generic, .Class and .Method) into
* that environment. Also copy any variables in the env of the
* generic that are not formal (or actual) arguments.
*
* 3. fix up the argument list; it should be the arguments to the
* generic matched to the formals of the method to be invoked */
```

Comment: I agree that this is why this is happening. But to "work around" this, if you want to modify the object that you're sending to the generic, you should pass it as the second parameter to `UseMethod()`. Also, it would be nice if you generic implementations all at least shared a common first argument. It's odd that `g.default()` does not have a parameter. This is where one would expect to pass the modified `x`.

Comment: @MrFlick -- But as you can see, even that second argument to `UseMethod` doesn't get passed along. It's only used to determine which method should be be dispatched (which in any case seems like the thing you should want from your generic function call). I agree with your general recommendation about how to structure the argument lists of the several methods.

Comment: @MrFlick -- I have to admit, though, that until now I hadn't appreciated that you *could*, if you wanted to, use `UseMethod()` to dispatch based on the values of several different supplied arguments (more like what happens with S4 classes). It would require a bit or preprocessing in the body of the generic, but seems like it wouldn't be too hard to accomplish. I wonder if that's used in any well known R packages.

Comment: I stand corrected. Seems that would not work for changing the first argument in the generic call stack.